# How can I detect interaction anywhere outside of a UIControl, non-invasively?

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I have a custom UIControl which, when tapped, goes into a confirm state and, when tapped again, performs the desired action.

I want to have this control go back into its initial state if the user interacts anywhere else on the screen. Is there a non-invasive way to achieve this?

**Clarification:** I consider code invasive if I can't contain it within this control. I'd like to give the dev of another app this code, which they could use to add the control to their app, without having to mess around with code anywhere else in the app. If this isn't possible, fine, but the question is how to accomplish this non-invasively.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a `UITapGestureRecognizer` placed on top of everything that triggers the dismiss only when the touch happens outside of you `UIControl` bounds.

Something like

```
- (void)presentConfirm {
   // whatever 

    self.dismissRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss:)];
    self.dismissRecognizer = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.dismissRecognizer];
}

- (void)dismiss:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // do stuff

    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.dismissRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(self.control.frame, touch));
}
```

Basically you're triggering the `dismiss` method only when the touch happens outside the `UIControl` frame (I assumed your control is referenced as `self.control`).

Also you're going to need a `dismissRecognizer` property declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissRecognizer;
```

and to prevent warnings you should also declare that your controller conforms to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to accomplish this with the touchesBegan method:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(myUIControl.isInConfirmState){ // check if your control is in confirmed state

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(myUIControl.frame, touchLocation)){
    // set myUIControl to it's initial state
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method would need to be put on a view covering the whole window, which would be invasive.

Comment: Well, drawing a button will cost you a thousand times more than checking an if expression on every touch.

Comment: Invasive as in I want to provide my code to someone else to integrate in their project, and I don't want them to have to mess with their other code, where possible.